# Multiplayer Timescale in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity where you can control your timescale. When adapting this to multiplayer (local multiplayer), obviously Time.timeScale would affect all gameobjects in the scene.

Now I know I can't make Time.timeScale work for individual gameobjects but I was wondering how I can effect the Update() frequency of all script in a gameobject or any other ways to do this.

I have tried setting the Time.timeScale to the desired number at the start of the Update() function and then resetting it at the end but it didn't work because Time.timeScale affects update frequency and when the thread is held up with the one function it can't affect any other scripts or gameobjects.

Comment: [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) does **not** change the framerate aka `Update` frequency! 

It basically rather is just a multiplier for how much virtual time passes in `Time.deltaTime` or the physics engine.

=>

If you need this on a per-player basis simply have your own multiplier and apply that one to your scripts `var someMovement = constant * Time.deltaTime * thisPlayerMultiplier;`

Comment: In general: How would you expect to have one player see everything slower or faster while everyone else experiences the same thing in normal time?

Comment: I tried using a multiplier on Time.deltaTime (just now) but because I'm using realistic physics for my car sim the car goes crazy and when slowing down time the car just stops. @derHugo

Comment: what realistic physics are you using? E.g. for the built-in `Physics` you could simply set `simulationMode = SimulationMode.Script` and then rather "manually" call `Simulate` with your reduced time multiplier .. in that case you would need individual physics scene for each player in order to simulate them independently